# NSFetchedResultsController with table like iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have Core Data database. Structure is on the image (DBContact have many DBMessages with property `messages`, each DBMessage have one contact with property `contact`):

[image]

I want to display messages grouped by contact and sorted by date. So the number of rows have to be = number of contacts with messages. And in each row I have to display avatar, nameAndSurname of contact and text and date of last message of this contact.

The only solution I found is:

```
    let entityName = kDBOrder
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        // sort
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "contact.id", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
        let sectionNameKeyPath: String? = "contact.id"
        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: nil)
       fetchedResultsController!.delegate = self
       if tableViewMain != nil {
          do {
             try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
          } catch {
             print("An error occurred in fetchresultcontroller")
          }
          tableViewMain.reloadData()
       }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count = 0
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
            let currentSection = sections[section]
            count = currentSection.numberOfObjects
            // in each section we must have only 1 row
            if count > 0 {
                count = 1
            }
        }
        return count
    }
```

But in this case contacts will be sorted by id, but I need to sort them by date of last message. But if I change sortDescriptors to fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false), NSSortDescriptor(key: "contact.id", ascending: false)]` to sort by date first, it will not display contacts properly.
Do anybody have ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably change the model to make life easier and do a little more processing earlier. Basically if add another relationship, 1-to-1, between the 2 entities and each time a new message is added is update that relationship - so you always have a direct pointer to the most recent message.

Once you've done that your FRC and your table load speed are trivial because you just use contacts in the fetch. New messages are also handled correctly because the relationship gets updated so the contact changes and the FRC will see it.

Comment: but I need to have filter by date and type of order, so this implementation will not work. Can you any other advice?

Comment: What do you mean type of order? You can still apply a predicate which uses the date.

Comment: Sorry, not order but message. The main issue is to filter by date. For example in contact "Fred" I will save last message "Hello", but if I change the date filter from 2 years ago to 1 year ago, this last message will not be relevant (the relevant message will be "Hello from me 1 year ago"), so this implementation will not work. Is there any other way to implement this. Right now I think, may be it will be better to use fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = "contact" (but in this case autoupdate of NSFetchedResultController will not work, that's why it would be great to find better solution)

Comment: That's a completely different requirement. You need to be able to see a list of users ordered by messages at an arbitrarily chosen date? What's the use case for that?

Comment: Actually yes, but it's not a chosen date, it's a Chosen Date Filter (so user chooses "from date" and "to date"), I need this, because the designer put the filter by date on the screen of messages.

Comment: Messages for a single user I can understand, but ordering users by messages they received in a date range is a bit strange. I cant think of a terribly efficient solution. It's going to be memory or processor intensive, so you need to go processor or you'll crash the app when a large date range is selected by someone with a lot of users and messages. Scrolling probably won't be great. I'd talk to the designer about the utility / UX benefits v cost...

Comment: Actually I created this Core Data scheme just for example.The actual scheme is: DBContact have many DBNumber (from phone book). DBNumber can have many DBOrders (operations of the electronic wallet). So it's important for user to be able to filter orders by date (for example to see orders until "now - 1 year".When user presses the cell, he will see full history of orders with this DBContact. I failed to use propertiesToGroupBy, because I'm in this case I will need to fetch only one property of contact (otherwise fetchresultcontroller will not work). May be it's better to use transient property?

Comment: it's probably better to not use an FRC for that part, use a fetch with a predicate on the orders and then use KVC collection operators to get the distinct contacts from the orders

Comment: but in this case I will get a list of Contacts, but I the table cells I need to display not only contacts, but last order date and last order sum of these contacts

Comment: you can get that from the array of orders too. you could also perhaps use `groupBy` and `max` to get only the last orders which matter, i haven't tried that and i'm not 100% sure it will work (usually you want the max, not each of the max's for a set of things)